# Can't gather IP of the visitor using Celular Data

Tags: php, database, visitor-statistic, cellular-network

I am trying to gather information about visitors and saving their info to database.

Ive finished database and php part today ( with some help ), when I tested the system, It saves IP address and other information via computers, tablets, phones using WiFi but it doesn't save-gather any information about phones using celular data.

What could be the problem ?

Here are the partial part of the code im using ;

```
include("counter/counter.php");
    $counter = new counter();


    $conn = mysql_connect($sn,$un,$pw);//server, username and password are your server address and access details

    if(!$conn)
    die("cannot connect to mysql server" . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

    $visitor_browser = getBrowserType();
    $ip_data = get_ip_info($ip);

    require_once("ip.codehelper.io.php");
    require_once("php_fast_cache.php");

    $_ip = new ip_codehelper();

    $real_client_ip_address = $_ip->getRealIP();
    $visitor_location       = $_ip->getLocation($real_client_ip_address);

    $guest_ip   = $visitor_location['IP'];
    $guest_country = $visitor_location['CountryName'];
    $guest_city  = $visitor_location['CityName'];
    $guest_state = $visitor_location['RegionName'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `visitor_info` (ipAdresi, browserTuru, sehirIsmi, sehirX, sehirY, bolgeIsmi, ulkeIsmi, ulkeKodu, ulkeX, ulkeY, saatTuruSehir, kitaIsmi, kitaKodu, toplamNufus, aramaKodu, alanCapi, dilTuru, paraBirimi, elektrikTuru) VALUES('".$real_client_ip_address."', '".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."', '".$visitor_location['CityName']."', '".$visitor_location['CityLatitude']."', '".$visitor_location['CityLongitude']."', '".$visitor_location['RegionName']."', '".$visitor_location['CountryName']."', '".$visitor_location['Country']."', '".$visitor_location['CountryLatitude']."', '".$visitor_location['CountryLongitude']."', '".$visitor_location['LocalTimeZone']."', '".$visitor_location['ContinentName']."', '".$visitor_location['ContinentCode']."', '".$visitor_location['Population']."', '".$visitor_location['CallingCode']."', '".$visitor_location['AreaSqKm']."', '".$visitor_location['Languages']."', '".$visitor_location['Currency']."', '".$visitor_location['Electrical']."')";
```

Why it doesn't gather information of phones using cellular data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected function getCountryNameFromIP()
     {

        $ip  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
           )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $answerIP = @file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=4b585e37503a519a408dc17878e6ec04fa963e1b946c567722538d9431c2d5cb&format=xml&ip=$ip" ,false,$context);

        if(isset($answerIP) && $answerIP !="")
        {
            $theResJ            =   simplexml_load_string($answerIP);
            $last_login_ip_cn   =   $theResJ->countryName;


            /**
            *   $last_login_ip_cc   =   $theResJ->countryCode;
            *   $last_login_ip_rc   =   $theResJ->regionCode;
            *   $last_login_ip_rn   =   $theResJ->regionName;
            *   $last_login_ip_cp   =   $theResJ->cityName;
            *   $last_login_ip_lat  =   $theResJ->latitude;
            *   $last_login_ip_lng  =   $theResJ->longitude;
            *   $last_login_zip_code=   $theResJ->zipCode;
            */
        }
        else
        {
            $last_login_ip_cn   =   "";
            /**
            *   $last_login_ip_cc   =   "";
            *   $last_login_ip_rc   =   "";
            *   $last_login_ip_rn   =   "";
            *   $last_login_ip_cp   =   "";
            * $last_login_ip_lat    =   "";
            *   $last_login_ip_lng  =   "";
            *   $last_login_zip_code=   "";
            */
        }

        return $last_login_ip_cn;
       }
```

> I hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution but I also tried your method since its simpler. I will be using part of it, thanks again.

Comment: although this solution gets the desired data but there is major draw back with this api. If you make more than one requests in one minutes .This api causes a delay and site gets hanged up. In return the site becomes extremely slow. So it is better you execute this script per session and store data in session for more use.